# Adding new files to a folder

Tags: java, file-io

I have created a blockchain solution and that works fine in principle but I need it so that every time the code gets executed, a new file is created in the folder. Currently it just keeps overwriting the file.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Prepend or append the current date (`yyyy-mm-dd-HH-MM-SS-ffffff`) to the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can get the current timestamp when creating the file. The timestamp is unique, so it will not have the problem of overwriting.

```
File f = new File("yourFileName"+System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

The below code should do your work. you can keep the new Filename as unique by using transaction id as the fileName.

```
String dir = "Some Path";
        File test = new File(dir + "newFileName");
        try {
            test.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

You can use the below code to get unique fileName:

```
public String getFileName() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
```

Comment: I have tried the above and all that it does is create a 1 new file the overwrites the same file when the code is ran again. Which is what it did in the first place. Unless i'm doing something wrong.. Thank you though!

Comment: make `getFileName()` method  static and then call it from the place where you want to create the file. For more help please add relevant code.